# Swift: is it possible to use generic and storyboard for UIViewController

Tags: xcode, swift, generics

let's say, I have UIViewController subclass:

```
class InformationServiceMenuVC <T : InformationServiceItemProtocol>: UITableViewController {

}
```

normally I can create instance of view controller by calling something like:

```
let vc = InformationServiceSideMenuVC<InformationServiceMenuItem>()
```

but **how do I pass needed generic type when use storyboard?**

Comment: Did you try setting the class in the storyboard to `InformationServiceSideMenuVC<InformationServiceMenuItem>`?

Comment: yes, it says unknown class and initialises UITableViewController instance

Answer (score 3):

Create a concrete class that inherits from the generic class:

```
class SpecificInformationServiceMenuVC : InformationServiceMenuVC<Specific> {}
```

Then you can use the specific subclass as your class type in storyboard.

It might even work to just make a typealias:

```
typealias SpecificInformationServiceMenuVC = InformationServiceMenuVC<Specific>
```

Comment: Inheritance won't compile since the derived class must be generic too. The typealias will do the job

Comment: Hmmm... that's unfortunate, it seems like it would be a fairly common practice.

Comment: I've tried using a typealias but that does not work either as of Xcode 6.1. I believe it is a bug that you cannot use generic classes, or typealiases, with storyboards.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3.0.1, I was able to refactor from this:

```
class TagPickerViewController: BaseViewController, HasAppController {
}
extension TagPickerViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
}
```

to:

```
class TagPickerViewControllerGeneric<TagViewModelClass: TagPickerViewModel>
    : BaseViewController {
}
class TagPickerViewController: TagPickerViewControllerGeneric<TagPickerViewModel>, 
    HasAppController, UITableViewDelegate {
}
```

While keeping `TagPickerViewController` in storyboard/xib. Hope it helps